# Pass model to mail view

Tags: laravel, email, eloquent

I have several methods that require email submissions. An example is, after making a purchase.

My class Mailable

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\Order;

class AfterOrder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    
    public $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->Order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        
        return $this->subject('Thanks for your purchase')->view('mail.after-order');
    }
}
```

My mail view

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Nombre: {{\Auth::user()->email}}</h1>
    <h1>Order: {{$order->reference}}</h1> 
</div>
```

My Controller

```
public function sendMail(Order $order) {
        $order = $order->newQuery();
        
        $order->whereHas('user', function($query){
                $query->where('email', '=', \Auth::user()->email);
            });
            
       $order = $order->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();    

        $user = User::where('email', '=', \Auth::user()->email)->first();
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new AfterOrder($order));


        //return redirect()->route('home')->with(['message' => 'Thank you for shopping at Sneakers!']);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? If I, for example, in my controller make a $ order-> reference I get the order reference but when passing the variable to the view it treats me as null or empty

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`with` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#via-the-with-method)

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('mail.after-order')
                ->with([
                   'orderName' => $this->order->name,
                   'orderPrice' => $this->order->price,
    ]);
}
```

in your mailable class `AfterOrder`. With that you have access to the `name` and the `price` of the order in your mail view.

You can then access these with `{{ $orderPrice }}` and `{{ $orderName }}` in your view.

Comment: Hello, thanks for commenting. I have tried to do `-> with ([
                        'orderReference' => $ this-> order-> reference
                    ]); `,  in the view I changed `$order->reference to orderReference` And now it's
                       `'orderReference' => $this- order->reference` which returns null

Answer (score 0):

Was a typo. just change `$this->Order = $order;` to `$this->order = $order;`

Comment: So if this solves your question please accept an answer to mark this question as solved.

Comment: i cant. "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"